# how to wrap selected text with special character and unwrap in contenteditable div Simple?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, getselection

Not any Kind of plugin reference given in answer.I am using already plugin wysiwyg editor.

```
function blanks(){
    wrap("*");
}

function wrap(tag) {
    var sel, range;
    var selectedText;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            selectedText = range.toString();
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode('|' + tag + selectedText + tag + '|'));
        }
    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text + "";
        range.text = '|' + tag + selectedText + tag + '|';
    }
```

Ref like that stackoverflow comment box text selected bold and remove bold.

Comment: Can you give us a jsFiddle of your code with every component (js, html, css). I think it is insufficient to say do like SO does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not equipped to answer this in specific methodology, but in conceptual terms, this is a simple task.

The content of the contenteditable container can be reduced to a string. A string is a list of characters. Each character has a position, or index, in this list.

Indexes are generally zero-based, so we'll assume that for this case.

If you would like to wrap a range of characters with a specific value, `CHAR`, it might look something like this:

`var result = 
    string.slice(0, index) + 
    CHAR + string.slice(index, size) + CHAR + 
    string.slice(index + size);`

Where `index` is the position of the first character, and `size` is the number of characters in the selection.